# Style Wordpress Custom Post Type Single Page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm registering a custom post type 'events'. The events can be listed using a shortcode, and when you click on an event you go to the single view of that event. Now, I want this single view page to be styled completely different using all of the event's metadata to create maps, images, etc, but I cannot figure out how. Using a template for this single view isn't an option since this is a plugin and should work with any theme. Just filtering the post's content isn't enough as I want to style the title too.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for you it's extremely simple.

All you have to do is create a new template called single-yourcustomposttype.php

I would recommend copying your single.php type and then modifying it, so that you keep in styling of your theme.

All the best!

Comment: I want this for work for any theme, so I can't just copy a theme's single.php

Comment: You can use a basic layout so you echo the header at the top and footer at the bottom (which will be theme specific) and then in between you can lay it out however you wish.